# Cannot read property 'offsetwidth' of undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What does it mean when I get the following error?

```
enter code here
```

code:

```
enter code here
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<spring:url var="css" value="/resources/css"/>
<spring:url var="js" value="/resources/js"/>
<spring:url var="images" value="/resources/images"/>


<c:set var="contextRoot" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath } "/>  



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="${css}/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="${css}/myapp.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3">

        <h1 class="my-4">Shop Name</h1>
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 3</a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

      <div class="col-lg-9">

        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide my-4" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item One</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Two</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Three</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Four</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Five</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Six</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2019</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </footer>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="${js}/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="${js}/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to read property `offsetWidth` of an element that does not exist or can't be found with the selector you use. Remove the `offsetWidth` and you will see that the object is `undefined`.

Comment: Please post your code. By the way the error was clear `Cannot read property 'offsetWidth'`

Comment: Agreed with @Cray

Comment: Mostly you have missed jquery link in your code, add this line in your `head` `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The error was clear that you are trying to read property `offsetWidth` of an element that doesn't have the selector you use or there is no such element. Remove the `offsetWidth` from the element or please verify that there exists an element like that

Another scenario is while using bootstrap plugins such as a slider with the missing class name or the code which doesn't follow the pattern that plugin have. In such conditions also may occur such error.

For Eg: bootstrap slider without set an `active` class on any of the slides.